# Copying with webclient to sharepoint document library question

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webdav

When I copy to a sharepoint document library using webclient, should the URL contain the destination filename or not?

For example:

```
client.UploadFile("http://site/projects/project/documentLibrary/subfolder/" , "PUT", attachmentFileName );
```

or

```
client.UploadFile("http://site/projects/project/documentLibrary/subfolder/" + attachmentFileName , "PUT", attachmentFileName );
```

Can't figure out which one works - because right now neither work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL **MUST** include the destination path.

The issue I was facing was easy to overlook, I was including the full file path in the URL, not just the file name.

Comment: Could you explain me what you described here? I'm trying to fix the same issue you had in 2009.